# Is it possible to build a VS Code extension that allows users to supply their own grammar?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to build a VS Code extension that allows users to locate their own grammar file and use that grammar file for syntax highlighting + grammar validation.

Would this be possible to do in VS Code using the yeoman generator? I was looking at this https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide

but if I create an extension with "New Language Support" I would have to specify my grammar, when instead I want users to supply their grammar that I then use to apply syntax highlighting and grammar validation with on other files.

Comment: Anything is possible given enough time, money and coffee.

Comment: I was hoping to get some pointers, I'm a bit stuck on what to do next.

Comment: It is not very hard if you develop a language server that loads grammar files on the fly to enable semantic highlighting, but it won't be easy as you do need experience on language server/grammars.

Comment: Yes, very possible and easy. But, besides the grammar for the language, you will need to encode rules for classes of symbols. Xpath expressions could specify the classification on the parse tree.

Comment: It might be possible to write an extension that generates new extensions from the grammar files and installs them. Alternatively, as @LexLi said, use semantic highlighting   which can be as dynamic as you want, instead of simple TextMate grammars.

Comment: Seemed like a good exercise, so I wrote an extension that does this, using an Antlr4 generated parser. Closest template in Yeoman you could modify would be Langium. http://codinggorilla.com/?p=2868